# Lufthansa economic flex refund policy

Tags: refunds, lufthansa

I'm looking into buying a lufthansa economic flex ticket so if something happens and I am forced to cancel my trip under any circumstance, then I can get my money back (I'd cancel the entire trip, outbound and inbound). My question is if I can just cancel my ticket and get my money back ? (I assume I'd have to pay some fee).

Comment: have you read the guidance on Lufthansa's site? I'm not sure we could give better info than that.

Comment: I tried reading it but it might be due to my lack of focus at the moment but it was quite unclear.

Comment: Is there something specific about the T&C that you don’t understand?

Comment: Yes, if I get my money back from cancelling my economic flex ticket or not.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Lufthansa's website for "Baggage & Other Fees"](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/baggage-and-other-fees), the "Fare overview Economy Class" section states that a Flex II ticket refund is free and has no fee.

[image: Lufthansa Fare overview Economy Class 2020]